# Core data crashing on delete of parent tablerow

Tags: uitableview, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm using ECSlidingViewController for a Path & FB style UI. Two UITableViews, one (The detail) is shown as the main view, the second (the master) is revealed as the sidemenu. Both powered by Core Data.

I'm getting a hard crash when deleting the parent table row in the sidemenu UITableView, but only when the detail page is showing the children of the parent row when deleted. All other rows delete as expected.

Deleting the row is handled by:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];
    }
}
```

I get the following error in the log:

> CoreData: error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (0) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (3), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out). with userInfo (null)

The `delete rule` is set to Nullify if that helps?

I'm guessing that Core Data is deleting ALL of the children in one go from the NSFetchedResultsController and then the UITableVIew is getting all confused?

How can I delete the parent and child NSManagedObjects without a crash?

Comment: After deleting the object, perform a new fetch and reload data. You could also use NSFetchResultsControllerDelegate for this. Hope it helps.

Comment: I can't delete the object without the crash. Single item deletes work fine. I don't understand why it is trying to delete all the child items at once.

Answer (score 0):

After going through the code many times it turns out that I had nested `[self.tableView beginUpdates]` and `[self.tableView endUpdates]` which were getting out of sync and I was calling endUpdates twice in a row.

I have hit this many times now developing this app. If you have a crash like this check and you are maybe using CoreDataTableViewController from the CS193P course check your use of beging and end updates!